# How to add a command line argument to a steam game?

Tags: steam, vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

I have Vampire Bloodlines, and it doesn't start by executing the "vampire.exe" file.

> Can't find Steam

I would like to add a `-window` argument to it, to start in the windowed mode, but the only shortcut that works is `steam://rungameid/2600` but it doesn't redirect the command k

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Steam Library, right click the game and go to `Properties`.  Click the `SET LAUNCH OPTIONS...` button, then add your command line arguments in the popup dialog.